# Is mutate a creature spell?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

When I play a creature for its mutate cost, is it still a creature spell?

For example if I play [Gemrazer](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Gemrazer) while [Animar, Soul of Elements](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Animar%2C%20Soul%20of%20Elements) is on the battlefield, will Animar get a +1/+1 counter?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Yes, a creature card cast for its mutate cost is still a creature spell.**

In the [Mutate rules](https://mtg.fandom.com/wiki/Mutate), rule 702.104a says

> Mutate appears on some creature cards. It represents a static ability that functions while the spell with mutate is on the stack. “Mutate [cost]” means “You may pay [cost] rather than pay this spell’s mana cost. If you do, **it becomes a mutating creature spell** and targets a non-Human creature with the same owner as this spell.” Casting a spell using its mutate ability follows the rules for paying alternative costs (see 601.2b and 601.2f–h).

Comment: Anecdotally, which is why they are so good in a Volo deck. 3 mutate trigger's for the price of 1